# How can I fix the memory leaks of this program, when I know what it leaks, most of the times?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

So, I have a dynamic array which leaks memory and I can almost always find out that all memory lost is lost in ONE block, and sometimes it didn't leak anything. However, I changed something, and now it always leaks, but it's a computable sum (I think it's the size of the array we last get before quitting the program). Can you please help me with this?

Here's the code if you want to look into it:

```
#include "DynamicVector.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

DynamicVector createDynamicVector() {
    DynamicVector dynamicVector;
    dynamicVector.number_of_elements = 0;
    dynamicVector.capacity = 2;
    dynamicVector.elements = (int *)malloc(dynamicVector.capacity * sizeof(int));
    return dynamicVector;
}

int isEmpty(DynamicVector *pointer) {
    if (pointer->number_of_elements == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int search_element(DynamicVector *pointer, int element) {
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < pointer->number_of_elements; index++) {
        if (pointer->elements[index] == element) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void resize_smaller(DynamicVector *pointer) {
    int *new_elements;
    new_elements = (int *)malloc((pointer->capacity * 3 / 4) * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(new_elements, pointer->elements, pointer->number_of_elements * sizeof(int));

    destroyDynamicVector(pointer);
    pointer->elements = new_elements;
    pointer->capacity = pointer->capacity * 3 / 4;
}

void resize_bigger(DynamicVector *pointer) {
    int *new_elements;
    new_elements = (int *)malloc(pointer->capacity * 2 * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(new_elements, pointer->elements, pointer->number_of_elements * sizeof(int));
    destroyDynamicVector(pointer);
    pointer->elements = new_elements;
    pointer->capacity = pointer->capacity * 2;
}

void add_element(DynamicVector *pointer, int element) {
    if (pointer->capacity == pointer->number_of_elements) {
        resize_bigger(pointer);
    }
    *(pointer->elements + pointer->number_of_elements) = element;
    pointer->number_of_elements++;
}

int remove_element(DynamicVector *pointer, int element) {
    int index_found = 0;
    index_found = search_element(pointer, element);
    if (index_found == -1) {
        return 1;
    }
    *(pointer->elements + index_found) = *(pointer->elements + pointer->number_of_elements - 1);
    pointer->number_of_elements--;
    if (pointer->number_of_elements < pointer->capacity / 2) {
        resize_smaller(pointer);
    }
    return 0;
}

void destroyDynamicVector(DynamicVector *pointer) {
    free(pointer->elements);
}
```

Comment: 'main' is missing

Comment: There might be some value in getting the program to `free` that last block, or at least investigating the cause, but keeping a single block around isn't a "leak" of the same seriousness as one which can potentially allocate more and more memory as the program runs. The OS will reclaim all the dynamic memory used for `malloc` purposes when the program exits, whether or not it was all `free`-d.

Comment: The code seems fine, except for huge vector sizes where `pointer->capacity * 3 / 4` might cause an integer overflow. You should post the structure definition and a `main()` function that exhibits the *leak*. It is possible that this *leak* be unrelated to your code: also explain what tool you are using to detect memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems fine, you should post the structure definition and a `main()` function that exhibits the *leak*. It is possible that this *leak* be unrelated to your code: also explain what tool you are using to detect memory leaks.

There is a small issue for huge vector sizes where `pointer->capacity * 3 / 4` might cause an integer overflow. This overflow could cause the `malloc()` to fail and return `NULL`, prompting undefined behavior when copying the array contents.

You could also use `realloc()` instead of `malloc()` for resizing, saving some copying if the block can be resized in place:

```
int resize_bigger(DynamicVector *pointer) {
    size_t new_capacity = pointer->capacity * 2;
    int *new_elements = realloc(pointer->elements, new_capacity * sizeof(int));
    if (new_elements != NULL) {
        pointer->elements = new_elements;
        pointer->capacity = new_capacity;
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

void resize_smaller(DynamicVector *pointer) {
    size_t new_capacity = pointer->capacity - pointer->capacity / 4;
    int *new_elements = realloc(pointer->elements, new_capacity * sizeof(int));
    if (new_elements != NULL) {
        pointer->elements = new_elements;
        pointer->capacity = new_capacity;
    }
}

// return the element number or -1 in case of failure
int add_element(DynamicVector *pointer, int element) {
    if (pointer->capacity == pointer->number_of_elements) {
        if (resize_bigger(pointer))
            return -1;
    }
    pointer->elements[pointer->number_of_elements] = element;
    return pointer->number_of_elements++;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew I had to add some catching if NULLs, but it was working fine. The issue was, when I copied it to Linux, I put destroy vector after return 0. But thanks a lot for helping me make my code better, I appreciate a lot!

Answer (score -1):

When you add element , you multiply size by 2 but when you remove element ou keep 3/4. That means that after adding one element and removing element the size will be 2*3/4=1.25 the original size.

Comment: This is not a leak, since the larger memory block is still managed. It's also a good idea, since it's fairly likely code which did that will want to grow the vector again later.